# How to replace entity in LQC?

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, containers, vaadin

I have Lazy Query Container (LQC) + hibernate connected to table. I don't want to display some collections at the table so some collections are lazy loaded.

When user select item (row) in table I want to open edit form with all data available. I have to initialize selected item - I get entity from Item, merge it back to context and call *hibernate.initialize*. it works fine, collections are initialized. But it is another instace then instance in container (because merge returns new instance)

1. How can I replace non-initialzied item with this new one?
2. Or how can I refresh the container and the table (how to select
   previously selected row in table after refresh?)